# Mysterious NSLayoutConstraints causing conflicts

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am using MGSplitViewClass [(link)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fmattgemmell%2FMGSplitViewController&ei=MF4IUbydNMyLqQH2jYG4BQ&usg=AFQjCNErwaoN6XZri_9QcsGE-vdT7Rfwjw&sig2=Dbcy4UFn5CNCt_d_a9MLqw&bvm=bv.41642243,d.aWM) and I'm having severe difficulty getting the size of a UICollectionView correctly set. In said split view I have in the master view a set of four UIViews that contain more robust views (table views, groups of labels, and a collection view).

First I tried to add the UICollectionView in my nib and programmatically created a collection view controller and connect it to my nib's collection view. This failed horribly as soon a I tried
`_collectionViewController.collectionView = myCollectionView;`.
This gave errors about the view from my nib being outside of the subtree
`'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to install constraint on view. Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view? That's illegal.`

Fine, now I'll remove the collection view from my nib and add the one the collection view controller comes with, like so.

```
_collectionViewController = [[[MyCollectionViewController alloc] initWithCollectionViewLayout: [[[MyCollectionLayout alloc] init] autorelease]] retain];
[_collectionViewController.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
UICollectionView* collectionView = _attachmentController.collectionView;
[_collectionViewContainer addSubview:collectionView];
```

This works but the collection view is overflowing the view container's size significantly and other layout issues. Now obviously the view will not scroll properly like this so I have to fix it.

So I add some constraints to get the view sized to fill the container view.

```
NSMutableArray* constraints = [[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[collectionView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(collectionView)] mutableCopy];
[constraints addObjectsFromArray:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|[collectionView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(collectionView)]];
for (NSLayoutConstraint* lc in constraints)
    [_attachmentViewContainer addConstraint:lc];
```

But this is where it gets screwy. Upon running this I get more layout errors.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d8c0b80 h=-&- v=-&- UICollectionView:0x1cb55400.midX == UIView:0x1d894300.midX - 10>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5a74b0 H:[UICollectionView:0x1cb55400]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d894300 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5a7440 H:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x1cb55400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d894300 )>"
```

and

```
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1d8c0d10 h=-&- v=-&- UICollectionView:0x1cb55400.midY == UIView:0x1d894300.midY + 437>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5a71a0 V:[UICollectionView:0x1cb55400]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d894300 )>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1c5a6f30 V:|-(0)-[UICollectionView:0x1cb55400]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x1d894300 )>"
```

Where did those random looking NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints come from? A better question is where can I get rid them? I cannot seem to find a single point in the code to jump in a kill them. `-viewWillAppear:` is not propagated past UIViewController so I'm sort of stuck.

Any thoughts are very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just before you add those constraints, try adding this line:

[collectionView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

The system will automatically translate the default autoresizing mask to constraints unless you set this to NO.

Comment: Well, that works wonders. Now I'm off to find to documentation that explains this in detail.

Comment: @macawm, You should check out the videos (there are 3) from WWDC 2012.

Comment: I remember these now. It has been a while since I watched them, since they were first released if I recall correctly. I will have to review them again. Thanks.